# Comparing character strings

Tags: java, algorithm

So I have a method which compares two character arrays that are inserted (s and t where s is the character array which should return true if is smaller ) and the aim is to find out whether one is less than the other (in dictionary order) to the first n characters.

```
public boolean lessCheck(char[] s, char[] t, int n) {
            int q = 0;
            if (t.length < n || s.length < n) {
                if (s.length != t.length) {
                    if (t.length < s.length) {
                        q = t.length;
                    } else {
                        q = s.length;
                    }
                } else {
                    q = t.length;
                }
            } else {
                q = n;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
                if (t[i] != s[i]) {
                    if (t[i] > s[i]) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (equal(s, t, n)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

The issue that I'm having is that whenever I sub

> s = bind, t = bin and n = 7
>   I get true.

This should return false as bind is less than bin in dictionary order...

Any help?

Comment: can you add your desired output for the test case
`s = bind, t = bin and n = 7`

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of ifs. The code is totally unreadable. Consider refactoring to many small functions first. Maybe then the problem will reveal itself.

Comment: Where is the equals methods?

Comment: One letter variable names are not helping with readability as well

Comment: The first chunk of code could be replaced with min and max function calls

Comment: Added the code for equals

Comment: To answer your question, from the code reading it looks like the `equal` method is at fault. Also the last if-else can be reduced to `return !equal(s,t,n);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to this piece of code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            if (t[i] != s[i]) {
                if (t[i] > s[i]) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

that should be

```
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            if (t[i] != s[i]) {
                if (t[i] > s[i]) {
                    return true;
                } else if (t[i] < s[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

In fact, if the condition t[i] > s[i] is NOT true, you still need to check whether t[i] < s[i] in order to return false.

I think a more compact version of your algorithm would be:

```
public static boolean lessThan(char[] s, char[] t, int n) {

    int minLength = Math.min(Math.min(s.length, t.length), n);

    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        if (s[i] < t[i]) {
            return true;
        } else if (s[i] > t[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return (minLength < n && s.length < t.length) ? true : false;
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, however s = binder t = binding n = 4 returns true, when should be false. If n number of characters match, should return false.

Comment: Ehi Addil, I think you checked my algorithm before my last edit. :) I'm checking now with your input and I'm getting false as expected.

Comment: Great!!! :) Just two additional considerations: 1) you should always check for input parameters correctness (s and t should be non-null and n should be a positive integer) 2) be sure to test it properly, it should be ok but you never know unless you prove it! :)

Answer (score 1):

> s = bind, t = bin and n = 7 I get true.

when called q=3

right?

the **for** loop compares the 3 chars **b,i,n**.

right?

The final **if** statement uses the **equal** method.
Lenghts of **bind** and **bin** are different and lower than n.

**equal** return false, right?

The final result you got is true, from the **else** block of the last **if**.

right?

The **String** class defines a **compareTo** method which should met your requirements:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

```
new String("bind").compareTo("bin")>0
new String("bin").compareTo("zoo")<0
new String("bin").compareTo("bin")==0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `equals` method returns `false` because the arrays are not the same length, then, because `equals` returned `false`, your `lessThan` method returns `true`.

There is no point in calling `equals` method after you compared almost all the characters. Instead of calling `equals` method, just check if s is shorter than t:

```
return s.length() < t.length();
```

If the subarrays are equal and one just shorter than the other, it means it will be placed before the longer array in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry couldn't resist the logic to find q. There is no need to find this q.

try this:

```
public boolean lessThan(char[] s, char[] t, int n) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, q = 0;
    while (i < s.length && i < t.length && (i < n)) {
        if (s[i] > t[i])
            return false;
        i++;
    }
    if (s.length > t.length)
        return false;
    else if (n < i)
        return true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: lessThan("binary", "bind", 7) = false - This should return true